# How can I edit a JSON element in-place, without rewriting the rest of the JSON object?

Tags: python, xml, json

I am receiving several objects, currently in JSON, and need to be able to modify parts of them, while leaving the later parts EXACTLY, space for space, bit for bit, identical.

For instance, Imagine I was receiving following object

```
{
"example": [
            {
                "Name": "Thing One",
                "Line2": "more text. ABCD\nEFG"
            },
            {
                "Name": "Thing Two",
                "Line2": "XYZZY..."
            }
            {
                "Name": "Thing Three",
                "Line2": [
                         {
                              "SubElement": "Sub1",
                              "SubElement": "Sub2"
                         ]
            }
        ]
}
```

If I want to the JSON object such that "Thing One" reads "Thing 111" while leaving Thing Three EXACTLY the way it is right now, is there any way to do that?

Right now, I'm converting it to a dictionary, modifying the element, then converting it back, but that doesn't work well for this scenario.

My fallback position is to convert to XML and use Regexes, but that's ugly.

Comment: I guess another way I could solve it would be to get the text representation of an element, then do a find/replace in the original string.. That's still not very safe...

Comment: Is every such replacement always going to the the exact same length?  If not, your question makes very little sense.

Comment: I want to be able to replace Thing One, and Thing Two, while leaving the Thing Three element untouched, so the THING THREE section retains the same MD5, even though the overall file MD5 will change.

Comment: @Colin Davis: How will anyone be able to tell?  Does each sub-object have a separate MD5 somewhere?  If so, what's wrong with simply fixing ALL the objects and providing ALL the revised MD5's?

Comment: Yes, each sub element's MD5 is being stored.

Comment: "My fallback position is to convert to XML and use Regexes, but that's ugly."  How does that preserve the structure of the JSON so that the MD5 is unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `object_pairs_hook` argument of the `json` load functions will allow you to use a `OrderedDictionary` such that you can retain the same order of the elements of JSON objects.

Answer (score 1):

The best answer to this question may be "Don't Do that."
If I need the bits to remain identical, I can replace "Thing Three" with a BASE64 or yENC encoded version of itself.

Comment: Edited to remove the "I'd rather find..." answer.

Comment: You don't need to provide status.  Stack Overflow maintains a complete history of all changes.  Just make the change and move on.

Comment: There are valid reasons for keeping whitespace in the json file. Readability is one reason.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution to this problem is to require the JSON to be in the most compact format. No whitespace, ;:, etc.
Reformatting it should be OK, so long as we always reformat to the same thing.

Comment: then you would prettyprint it for reading and then compacting it again?